# create thumbnails on laravel with ffmpeg

Tags: php, laravel, ffmpeg

i want to create a thumbnails on video that uploaded, i've been using mmpeg, i've been try this code but it not working yet

this is my code on controller

```
use ffmpeg\FFMPEG;

    public function store(Request $request)
{

    $news = new News;

    $filename = $request->file('attachment')->getClientOriginalName();
    $request->file('attachment')->storeAs('attachment', $filename);

    $thumbnails = new FFMPEG;
    $thumbnails->getThumbnails($filename, 'thumbnails', 5);
}
```

i've been also setting on config/app.php like this

```
LinkThrow\Ffmpeg\Provider\FfmpegServiceProvider::class, //providers
```

`'FFMPEG' => LinkThrow\Ffmpeg\Facade\FfmpegFacade::class, //aliases`

the error is

> Class 'ffmpeg\FFMPEG' not found

is there need to setting up on config/ffmpeg.php too ?

Answer (score 0):

As per me there are two possibility  one is   `use FFMPEG\FFMPEG;` you are using small letter.
update s follows

```
use FFMPEG\FFMPEG;

public function store(Request $request)
{

    $news = new News;

    $filename = $request->file('attachment')->getClientOriginalName();
    $request->file('attachment')->storeAs('attachment', $filename);

    $thumbnails = new FFMPEG;
    $thumbnails->getThumbnails($filename, 'thumbnails', 5);
}
```

Second one is you have use instead of this

```
$thumbnails = new FFMPEG;
$thumbnails->getThumbnails($filename, 'thumbnails', 5);
```

to

```
FFMPEG::getThumbnails($filename, 'thumbnails', 5);
```

Comment: hi, thanks for your help, i've been following your way, but its still error, and the error still the same :(

Comment: @rafitio.i also tried by installing that package .but getting same error.let me try.i think package is not installing properly

Comment: oh ok, i'll try to find another package and reinstall it.
thank you :)

Comment: @rafitio.i also used first time this package today.so dont know exact issue .you try any othere package.or someone can help you stackoverflow